# Can I arrange my study labels in a forest plot using study years after specifying the byvar to be something different? (Meta package-R)

Tags: r, statistics, meta, r-forestplot, metafor

Can I arrange all my study labels within subgroups in my forest plot with the year of publication after specifying that I want subgroups divided by a certain variable?

Here is the code I am currently using.

brugia.forest <- metaprop(event = no.positive, n = no.tested, studlab = studylabel, data = brugia, byvar = diagnostics, bylab = c("direct detection", "direct and indirect detection", "indirect detection"), print.byvar = F, sm = "PLO", method.tau = "REML", title = "", hakn = T)

I would like the studies within the "diagnostics" groups to be arranged from the oldest to the most recent and not alphabetically as is currently the case. I am using the **meta** package of R because of its user-friendliness and would like to continue using it (so, **metafor** suggestions may not be too helpful)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer this question because the creator of the meta package, Dr. Guido Schwarzer was kind to answer the question via email. Here is the way forward:

By default, the forest function does not sort the studies at all,
instead the order of the dataset is used. One can therefore order the dataset before utilising it for the forestplot first.

Alternatively, one can use the 'sortvar' function to change the order of studies and specify the variable one wants to sort the studies by.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `ggplot` if you are familiar with the ggplot package. Gives a lot of flexibility in arranging and modifying the plots